# Deserialize JSON with dynamic root name

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following working codes which de-serialize a JSON message. As you can see, the JSON message has root name "response", and I have also annotated the Response class accordingly to indicate so. However, in reality the JSON message will be received from another system and the root name could be anything beside "response". How do I handle different root names?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.As;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.Id;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String responseMessage =
                "{" + 
                "  \"response\" : {" + 
                "    \"body\" : {" + 
                "      \"country\" : \"Vietnam\"" + 
                "    }" + 
                "  }" + 
                "}";
        Response response = mapper.readValue(responseMessage, Response.class);
    }

}

class Body {

    private String country;

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

}

@JsonTypeName("response")
@JsonTypeInfo(include = As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = Id.NAME)
class Response {

    private Body body;

    public Body getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(Body body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to deserialize it as a `Map<String, Body>`. To do this by hand, you'll need to use this:

```
mapper.readValue(response, new TypeReference<Map<String, Body>>() {})
```

Note that if you're using a framework like Spring (which you usually should be), then you should let the framework handle serialization for you.

Comment: Sorry, your answer does not work. I'm getting com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "body", not marked as ignorable (one known property: "country"])

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in two ways

**Make Response,Body classes as static**

```
    static class Body {

        private String country;

        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public void setCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
        }

    }

    @JsonTypeName("response")
    @JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
    static class Response {

        private Body body;

        public Body getBody() {
            return body;
        }

        public void setBody(Body body) {
            this.body = body;
        }
    }
```

or
**Make Response,Body classes as public**

- create new class file with name Body.java

```
public class Body {

        private String country;

        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public void setCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
        }

    }
```

and

- Response.java file

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;

@JsonTypeName("response")
@JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
public class Response {

    private Body body;

    public Body getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(Body body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

}
```

Then call the main method

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String responseMessage =
                "{" +
                        "  \"response\" : {" +
                        "    \"body\" : {" +
                        "      \"country\" : \"Vietnam\"" +
                        "    }" +
                        "  }" +
                        "}";
        Response response = mapper.readValue(responseMessage, Response.class);
        System.out.println(response.getBody().getCountry());
}
```

Reason for issue:

> The basic reason for Jackson's refusal to try use non-static inner
>   classes for deserialization (serialization actually works fine) is
>   because there is no general way to instantiate such classes -- there
>   is no zero-argument constructor, nor @JsonCreator annotated other
>   constructors or factory methods (or single-String-argument
>   constructors, but I digress). Jackson can not instantiate them.
>
> In theory one could handle this case if it was known what the
>   enclosing parent class instance was. But realistically this is both
>   complicated and unnecessary -- typically omission of "static" is
>   either accidental, or incidental, and can be added to make things
>   work.

Ref: http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/08/entry_411.html

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom deserialiser which will skip wrappers or use `@JsonAnySetter` annotation. See below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String responseMessage =
        "{  \"response\" : {"
            + "    \"body\" : {"
            + "      \"country\" : \"Vietnam\""
            + "    }"
            + "  }"
            + "}";
    Response response = mapper.readValue(responseMessage, Response.class);
    System.out.println(response.getBody());
  }
}

class Body {

  private String country;

  // getters, setters, toString
}

class Response {

  private Body body;

  @JsonAnySetter
  public void setAny(String anyPropertyName, Map<String, Body> body) {
    for (Body item : body.values()) {
      this.body = item;
    }
  }

  // getters, setters
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Body{country='Vietnam'}
```